# Excel VBA FormatConditions in Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to convert the following code into python:

```
            Columns("C:C").Select
            Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual _
                , Formula1:="=50"
            Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5296274
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
```

And I have the following python code for it:

```
                wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").Select
            formula1 = "=50"
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions.Add(excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual, formula1,formula2)
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(excel.Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority() 
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(1).Font.Bold = True
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(1).Italic = False
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(1).Font.Strikethrough = False
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(1).Font.TintAndShade = 0
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(1).Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 5296274
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
            wb.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AA").FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
'<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x174381576>' object has no attribute 'XlFormatConditionType'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably change

```
excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue
excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual
```

to

```
win32com.client.constants.xlCellValue
win32com.client.constants.xlGreaterEqual
```

Comment: @S.Mark I am getting the following:

global name 'win32com' is not defined

Comment: @ichigo, imm, `import win32com` ?

Comment: @S.Mark one last question, I am trying to reuse this code twice for 2 different conditions. Excel doesn't seem to take the last condition, how come?

Comment: @ichigo, to use the code many time, you might need to make a function and call it by passing some cell location variables, but I am afraid I am not so familiar with excel library actually. I was just answering based on your error msg. may be you could make another question and ask for how to make function to use in your excel file access.